# How to prevent continuity problem in datetime index using tz_localize?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am using a datetime index dataframe and I want to localize it in Europe.

So i used tz_localize as follow :

```
file = 'data.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(file,sep=";", header=0)
df['datetime']=pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'],dayfirst=True)
df['datetime']=df['datetime'].dt.tz_localize('Europe/Berlin',nonexistent='shift_forward')
df=df.interpolate(method='pad')
df=df.set_index(['datetime'])
df=df.sort_index(ascending=True)
```

My problem is that I have a missing value and a double value on march 31 2019 as show in  this example

```
df=pd.date_range(start='03/31/2019', end='04/01/2019',freq='H')

data = np.random.randint(1, high=100, size=len(df))
df = pd.DataFrame({'index': df, 'A': data})
df = df.set_index('index')
df=df.tz_localize('Europe/Berlin',nonexistent='shift_forward')
```

Here is how it looks

[image]

As you see I got 2 values for 3 AM and no value for 2 AM which is problematic for the rest of my code.

Is there an easy way to prevent this and change one of the 3 AM value in a 2 AM one, in order to avoid continuity problems?

Thanks a lot and have a nice day

Edit :

I tried to dodge the probleme by doing this

```
for i in range (len(df)):
    
if df.loc[str(df['year'][i])+'-01':str(df['year'][i])+'-06']:
    df=df.tz_localize('Europe/Berlin',nonexistent='shift_backward')
    df=df.interpolate(method='pad')
else :
    df=df.tz_localize('Europe/Berlin',nonexistent='shift_forward')
    df=df.interpolate(method='pad')
```

But I got this error message

ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the time for 2 AM does not exist because there is a variation in time on that day in Germany (Berlin) (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summer_time_in_Europe)).
The parameter `nonexistent` in `df=df.tz_localize('Europe/Berlin',nonexistent='shift_forward')` with `shift_foreward` changes that invalid time (2 AM) to the next valid one (3 AM).

I would suggest you to generate the date_range directly for that timezone so that no duplicate index will be generated:
`df = pd.date_range(start='03/31/2019', end='04/01/2019',freq='H',tz='Europe/Berlin')`.
You still have your problem with continuity. You can either insert now a value manually or consider updating your other code so that this "time jump" is not problematic (it is correct, 2 AM just does not exist).

Note that in the end of October the same thing happens reversed.

Edit: to insert a fake value:

```py
df = pd.date_range(start='03/31/2019', end='04/01/2019',freq='H',tz='Europe/Berlin')
df = pd.DataFrame({'index': df, 'A': data})
# this line inserts the invalid index
# i don't know if it should be 02:00:00+01:00 or 02:00:00+02:00 as it isn't a real date
df.loc[-1] = [pd.Timestamp("2019-03-31 02:00:00+01:00"), np.random.randint(1, high=100)]
df=df.set_index(['index'])
df=df.sort_index(ascending=True)
```

Comment: Yes I figured that out, I haven't the problem in October because of the "shift_forward" parameter, that's why I thought may be I could shift forward for half the year and shift backward for the other half but it seems that I'm doing it wrong :/

Could i fake a 2 AM value which will take one of the two 3AM value?

Comment: @SonnePer i updated the answer to include an example on how to insert a fake value